# Virtualization and LAN redundancy

Tags: virtualization, lan

I am starting the design to support virtualized environment for an existing middleware system running on Linux and Solaris today.
This system uses dual internal and external LANs for redundancy and we have implemented a mechanism to change the routing in the switches and servers in case one of the LAN fails.

I am wondering in virtualized environment, is it still worth doing that or can the virtualization layer take care of that for me and provide a unique virtual LAN that will use both existing physical LANs to provide me an uninterrupted virtual LAN or do I need to handle the dual LAN also in the virtual machines (but then several VMs could act on the same physical switches which will be an issue).

I plan to support VMWare and KVM.